# get only numeric value from start of the string sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to sort the rows base on the number in a sql query. But the field type is varchar and **may contain an alphabet with the number**. like

```
5A
22A
5
7
51
57C
3
51D
```

Sort result should be like

```
3
5
5A
7
22A
51
51D
57C
```

I used this query

```
order by CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(CNNO, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', CNNO), LEN(CNNO)))
```

But it only works with value like W20,P55 but 20W, 55P can not be processed.

Comment: Ideally, it seems like that the numerical and non-numerical parts of your string should be in 2 different columns; one an `int` and the other a `(var)char`. Expecting a string type data type to sort like a numerical value is a mistake; they have very different sorting methods.

Comment: Also, in your closing sentence you talk about values like `'W20'` and `'P55'`, but these aren't in your sample data or expected results. Is `W` (the number?) greater than or less than `57`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your numbers are at the *beginning* of the strings.  This works for the data you have provided:

```
select v.*, left(cnno, patindex('%[^0-9]%', cnno +'A') - 1)
from (values ('5A'),
             ('22A'),
             ('5'),
             ('7'),
             ('51'),
             ('57C'),
             ('3'),
             ('51D')
     ) v(cnno)
order by try_convert(int, left(cnno, patindex('%[^0-9]%', cnno + 'A') - 1)), cnno;
```

Comment: order by CONVERT(int, LEFT(CNNO, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', CNNO + 'A') - 1)) works for me. Thank you so much.